# How to share Command config without inheritance?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, architecture

Assume I have one command having the `receiver` argument in order to greet someone:

```
class PlainTextHelloWorldCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('text:hello')
            ->addArgument('receiver', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Who do you want to greet?');
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface  $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int|null|void
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $receiver = $input->getArgument('receiver');
        $output->writeln("Hello {$receiver}!");
    }
}
```

Yet another command now also would need the `receiver` argument:

```
class HtmlHelloCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('html:hello')
            ->addArgument('receiver', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Who do you want to greet?');
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface  $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return int|null|void
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $receiver = $input->getArgument('receiver');
        $output->writeln("<html><h1>Hello {$receiver}!</h1></html>");
    }
}
```

I am now thinking on how not to repeat myself.

I want to share the logic to both

- add the argument
- parse the input

so that it is at one place.

I know I could create a `ReceiverAwareCommand`, yet what happens if I get more arguments?

I don't want to to have

```
class SendEmailCommand extends MessageAwareGreeterCommand 
                       extends ReceiverAwareCommand
                       extends ...
```

which is why I like to avoid inheritance.

Also, my example is simplified in so far as the two example commands do basically the same. That's not necessarily the case.

Furthermore, I have about 10 arguments, whereas each command may need at most 4 of them.

And I only want to set those arguments when needed without myself.

I was thinking in the direction of the Decorator pattern, yet I am bit confused on how to set it up in this case, so it *feels* wrong.

Hence I am wondering: How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried to call *parent::configure();* before adding new arguments with `$this->setName('html:hello') …` to the child class? It should add the arguments to the parent class arguments.

Comment: @A.L The point is to avoid inheritance. And yes, then I would need to do `parent::configure()` and `parent::execute()`. It's just not a route I want to be going in case as there are multiple arguments in different forms required for one command.

Comment: Have you tried to use only one command with several optional arguments? You'll be able to switch between html or text inputs, etc.

Comment: I want the commands to define properly that certain commands are required or optional. I don't want a base command that has all the commands as optional. Because they are not. It should be explicit want arguments a command need.

Comment: This might be a case where copy/paste could be your friend.  But I suppose you could inject a configurator/parser object that would be smart enough to configure each command as needed.  Seems like overkill unless you are talking about dozens of commands.

Answer (score 1):

As symfony 4.

I create a class called Configure and add 3 static functions in it.

```
namespace MyApp\Commands;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\{InputInterface, InputArgument, InputOption};

class Configure {
    static function arguments(Command $command, array $arguments) {
        foreach($arguments as $argument) {
            // Include here all of your re-useable arguments.
            switch($argument) {
                case 'arg1':
                    $command->addArgument('arg1', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Description.');
                break;
                case 'arg2':
                    $command->addArgument('arg2', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Description');
                break;
                // ...
                // Add more here.
            }
        }
    }

    static function options(Command $command, array $options) {
        foreach($options as $option) {
            // Include here all of your re-usable options.
            switch($option) {
                case 'opt1':
                    $command->addOption('opt1', NULL, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '.');
                break;
                case 'opt2':
                    $command->addOption('opt2', NULL, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '.');
                break;
                // ...
                // Add more here.
            }
        }
    }

    static function validate(InputInterface $input) {
        // Include here all of your default validations.
        if ($input->getOption('opt2') && !$input->getOption('opt1'))
            throw new \Exception('You must send --opt1 when sending --opt2');
        // ...
        // Add more here.
    }
}
```

In my commands I pick and choose what arguments/options should be re-used.

```
namespace MyApp\Commands;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\{InputInterface, InputArgument, InputOption};
use Symfony\Component\Console\{Command\Command, Output\OutputInterface};

class MyCommand extends Command {
    protected static $defaultName = 'my:command';

    protected function configure() {
        // Here you set the arguments/options that are unique to this
        // command.
        $this
            ->setDescription('Description.')
            ->addOption('only_here', 'o', NULL, 'Description.');

        // You can pick and choose which of your default arguments/option
        // should be included in this command.
        Configure::arguments($this, ['arg1', 'arg2']);
        Configure::options($this, ['opt2']);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        Configure::validate($input);
        // ...
        // My stuff here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I know that you don't want inheritance but I can't find a better idea)

---

You can define a `BaseCommand` where you define all the arguments by adding methods `add…Argument`:

```
class BaseCommand extends Command
{
    static $format = '%s';

    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        // Define a fake command (IIRC Symfony throws an error without this).
        $this
            ->setName('command:base')
            ->setDescription('Base command')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        parent::initialize($input, $output); //initialize parent class method

        $receiver = $input->getArgument('receiver');
        $output->writeln(sprintf($this::$format, $receiver));
    }

    /***** Define arguments *****/
    protected function addReceiverArgument()
    {
        $this
            ->addArgument('receiver', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Who do you want to greet?')
        ;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function addOtherArgument()
    {
        $this
            ->addArgument('other', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Other argument')
        ;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then you can reuse these methods in the child classes:

```
class PlainTextHelloWorldCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this
            ->setName('text:hello');

        $this
            ->addReceiverArgument()
        ;
    }
}
```

And if another command need 2 arguments, it's easy:

```
class HtmlHelloCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    // Change the output formatting.
    static $format = '<html><h1>Hello %s!</h1></html>';

    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this
            ->setName('html:hello')
        ;

        $this
            ->addReceiverArgument()
            ->addOtherArgument()
        ;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the commands:

```
$ php app/console text:hello aaa
Hello aaa!
$ php app/console html:hello aaa


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  Not enough arguments (missing: "other").                

$ php app/console html:hello aaa bbb
<html><h1>Hello aaa!</h1></html>
```